# What represents Math.IEEERemainder(x,y) in C++?

Tags: c++

What represents **Math.IEEERemainder(x,y)** in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [fmod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/) function.

Comment: +1. Answers to the effect of "use the modulus operator" miss the point that modulus is not the same operation as fmod.

Comment: It takes 18 characters to express in C# what C++ can say in four. It's like an allegory.

Comment: @Crashworks: Indeed.  C# uses 18 characters to clearly express intent, while C++ mumbles what sounds like a curse.

Comment: Except that `Remainder` expresses what the function does much better than `fmod`. EDIT: Ninja'd by Michael.

Comment: `fmod` is a different function with different numerical properties and applications.  It’s not enough to point at it without explaining the differences (and we have `std::remainder`now anyway).

Answer (score 5):

In the C++11 standard library, `std::remainder(x,y)`, is now the equivalent function of C#'s `Math.IEEERemainder(x,y)` in C++.

From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder

> *Computes the IEEE remainder of the floating point division operation `x/y`*

The IEEE remainder is `x–(round(x/y)*y)`

Whereas, the `fmod` remainder is `x - trunc(x/y)*y`, which can lead to different answers such as was raised in this question: [Why am I getting a different result from std::fmod and std::remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519082/why-am-i-getting-a-different-result-from-stdfmod-and-stdremainder)

If you really want to get the IEEE-defined remainder, you need `std::remainder(x,y)` (or define your own function if you can't use C++11)

Answer (score 2):

Although marked as the answer, SLak's answer is not correct.

Yes both calculate a modulo, but they differ in how signs are treated. (ie. John Feminella is correct). An implementation (and links in to the MSDN documentation) can be found here:

[Is Math.IEEERemainder(x,y) equivalent to x%y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971645/is-math-ieeeremainderx-y-equivalent-to-xy)

Note that the IEEERemainder() function implements modulo in an IEEE standard manner - rather than what K&R thought of back in the early 70s.