# Why am I getting a different result from std::fmod and std::remainder

Tags: c++, floating-point

In the below example app I calculate the floating point remainder from dividing `953` by `0.1`, using `std::fmod`

What I was expecting is that since `953.0 / 0.1 == 9530`, that `std::fmod(953, 0.1) == 0`

I'm getting `0.1` - **why is this the case?**

Note that with `std::remainder` I get the correct result.

That is:

```
std::fmod     (953, 0.1) == 0.1 // unexpected
std::remainder(953, 0.1) == 0   // expected
```

#### Difference between the two functions:

According to [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com)

- `std::fmod` calculates the following:

exactly the value `x - n*y`, where `n` is `x/y` with its fractional part truncated

- `std::remainder` calculates the following:

exactly the value `x - n*y`, where `n` is the integral value nearest the exact value `x/y`

**Given my inputs I would expect both functions to have the same output. Why is this not the case?**

### Exemplar app:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

bool is_zero(double in)
{
    return std::fabs(in) < 0.0000001;
}

int main()
{
    double numerator   = 953;
    double denominator = 0.1;

    double quotient = numerator / denominator;
    double fmod     = std::fmod     (numerator, denominator);
    double rem      = std::remainder(numerator, denominator);

    if (is_zero(fmod))
        fmod = 0;
    if (is_zero(rem))
        rem = 0;

    std::cout << "quotient: " << quotient << ", fmod: " << fmod << ", rem: " << rem << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
quotient: 9530, fmod: 0.1, rem: 0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to floating point math. Here's what happens: One tenth cannot be represented exactly in binary, just as one third cannot be represented exactly in decimal. As a result, the division produces a result slightly below 9530. The floor operation produces the integer 9529 instead of 9530. And then this leaves 0.1 left over.

Comment: Then why does `int(953/.1) == 9530`? If your assertion is correct, shouldn't that be truncated to `9529` too?

Comment: a better answer, in my opinion, is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39966752/364084. It explains the discrepancies between the expected result if we go by the documentation of fmod() and the actual result. And it is due to the usage of remainder() inside fmod() implementation.

Answer (score 12):

Because they are different functions.

[`std::remainder(x, y)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder) calculates [IEEE remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) which is `x - (round(x/y)*y)` where `round` is [rounding half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) (so in particular `round(1.0/2.0) == 0`)

[`std::fmod(x, y)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) calculates `x - trunc(x/y)*y`. When you divide `953` by `0.1` you may get a number slightly smaller than 9530, so truncation gives 9529. So as the result you get `953.0 - 952.9 = 0.1`

Comment: What he doesn't understand is why `fmod` returns 0.1 -- and you didn't explain that.

Comment: "std::remainder(x,y) calculates x-(round(x/y)*y)" - Does it actually? For instance, std::remainder(1.0,2.0) is 1.0, whereas (1.0-round(1.0/2.0)*2.0) is -1.0. This is with g++ 7.3.0.

Comment: @user2258552 `round(1.0/2.0) == 0` by IEEE definition (quite weird) - I've edited my answer to clarify that. Thanks for pointing out.