# is remainder(x,y) really x-((round(x/y)*y)?

Tags: c, fmod

Reading the answer of [@anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959454/anton-savin) in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519082/why-am-i-getting-a-different-result-from-stdfmod-and-stdremainder) I tried to see if really `remainder(x, y)` is exactly `x-(round(x/y)*y)`.

Running the code for the value of `x=5.` and `y=2.`. I got:

```
printf("the value of remainder is %f\n",remainder(x, y));
printf("the value of remainder is %f\n",x-(round(x/y)*y));
```

> the value of remainder is 1.000000
>
> the value of remainder is -1.000000

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) :

> Floating point **remainder**. This is not like a normal modulo operation,
>   it can be negative for two positive numbers. It **returns the exact**
>   **value of x–(round(x/y)·y)**.

Is the explanation of Anton wrong, or am I missing something ?

Comment: The formula assumes that x and y are floating point, not integers.

Comment: @RaymondChen -_- if they were integers I will get the correct answer ! No comment !

Comment: IEEE uses banker's rounding.  They think round(2.5) should be 2 and not 3.

Comment: @HansPassant is `nearbyint()` function using banker's rounding ?

Comment: It uses the rounding mode set by std::fesetround().  No bankers in the C++ standardization committee.

Comment: Sorry, what's the meaning of `round()` in the wikipedia context? can you edit your question and add a definition of `round()` function?

Comment: check the hans Passant comment which is above. It is banker's rounding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight difference in what `remainder` does.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/remainder):

> The remainder() function computes the remainder of dividing x by y.
>   The return value is x-n*y, where n is the value x / y, rounded to the
>   nearest integer. **If the absolute value of x-n*y is 0.5, n is chosen to
>   be even.**

So in the halfway case the rounding part performed by `remainder` does not round away from zero, but instead rounds to the *nearest even number*.

Comment: so I should use `nearbyint()` function instead ?

Comment: Good answer (+1). Might want to add in a link/reference to [banker's rounding](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BankersRounding) so OP can learn more about different rounding algorithms and their error bounds. :)

Comment: I will check your answer if you provide a link for that !

Comment: @rondino Added the link.  Also changed quoted test as the wording differs from my local man page (the meaning is the same, though).