# output of fmod function c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, fmod

Given:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    double h = .1;
    double x = 1;
    int nSteps = abs(x / h);

    double rem = fmod(x, h);
    cout<<"fmod output is "<<rem<<endl;
    if(abs(rem)<std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
        cout<<"fmod output is almost near 0"<<endl;

    rem = remainder(x,h);
    cout<<"remainder output is "<<rem<<endl;
    if(abs(rem)<std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
        cout<<"remainder output is almost near 0"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Given `int(x/h) == 10`, I would have expected the `fmod()` result to be near 0 but what i get is .0999999999. It is a significant difference. The result of remainder() still seem acceptable. Code could be tried at  http://ideone.com/9wBlva

Why this significant difference for fmod() result?

Comment: C++ and C Arent the same langauge

Comment: If that does not answer your question on its own, read the docs. `fmod` and `remainder` don't do the same thing, so different results are to be expected.

Comment: @amanuel2 u get similar results  http://ideone.com/rLyS2t

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I'm still a little confused. The documentation on [fmod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) states that "The floating-point remainder of the division operation x/y calculated by this function is exactly the value x - n*y, where n is x/y with its fractional part truncated.", but if I explicitly compute that myself, I get a result of 0 while fmod still returns 0.1. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f36cbeafc648a639).
If I use `float` instead of `double`, the value comes out as expected [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5916ae514c3c94ff)

Comment: @wanderer Just because a program happens to work in both a C++ Compiler and a C Compiler doesn't make it so , that C++ And C Are the same language.

Comment: @amanuel2  The example i posted for C is C code. I should consider it end of this discussion.

Comment: I mean, the underlying diagnosis of my dupe vote is most likely still correct because `.1` cannot be represented exactly in C++ `double`s (IEEE-754 `double`s, to be more precise), but I guess [this output](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/serNuFI4wFLOpOaj) could need some more explanation.

Comment: @BaummitAugen   I see similar issues when using 2 and 0.2. I can't help but feel there's something I'm not getting, so I'm afraid of voting to reopen.

Comment: @wanderer Two things , first of all there is no concept of namespaces in C, Second of all [**Do Not Use `using namespace std;` !!**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) . There is a reason why your question is tagged C++ , please think before tagging , so you dont spam other tags. Thankyou!

Comment: @amanuel2: What do you mean there is no concept of namespaces in C++? We use them all the time. Second, for use in a small toy example like this it's no problem, though not recommended.

Comment: @AndyG I Meant to type C . Mistype

Comment: @AndyG Unsurprisingly, the problem goes away when using 1, .25 which are represented exactly ([Live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wgw3jq541zEGuP6y)). Now the question is why `int(1/.1)` yields 10 instead of 9.

Comment: @AndyG As of the time of your comment, I already reopened it. ;)

Comment: The value `0.1` cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point. The actual value of `h` is most likely `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`, which can be represented exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is that the version of `fmod` you're using appears to follow the implementation defined at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod):

```
double fmod(double x, double y)
{
    double result = std::remainder(std::fabs(x), (y = std::fabs(y)));
    if (std::signbit(result)) result += y;
    return std::copysign(result, x);
}
```

`std::remainder` computes a very very small result, nearly zero (-5.55112e-17 when using 1 and 0.1 for me, -1.11022e-16 for 2 and 0.2). However, what's important is that the result is *negative*, which means [`std::signbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) returns true, causing `y` to get added to the result, effectively making the result equal to `y`.

Note that the documentation of `std::fmod` doesn't say anything about using `std::remainder`:

> The floating-point remainder of the division operation x/y calculated by this function is exactly the value x - n*y, where n is x/y with its fractional part truncated.

So if you compute the value yourself, you do end up with zero (even if you use `std::round` on the result instead of pure integer truncation)

We see similar problems when `x` is 2 and `y` is 0.2

```
double x = 2;
double y = .2;

int n = static_cast<int>(x/y);
double result = x - n*y;
std::cout << "Manual: " << result << std::endl;
std::cout << "fmod: " << std::fmod(x,y) << std::endl;
```

Output ([gcc demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/249620f2da07a9de)) is

> Manual: 0 
>   fmod: 0.2

However the problem is not relegated to only gcc; I also see it in MSVC and clang. In clang there is sometimes different behavior if one uses `float` instead of `double`.

This really small negative value from `std::remainder` comes from the fact that neither 0.1 nor 0.2 can be represented exactly in floating point math. If you change x and y to, say 2 and 0.25, then all is well.

Comment: For `fmod`: *"is exactly the value x - n\*y, where n is x/y with its fractional part truncated."* And by `int(x/h) == 10`, `n` should be `10` and thus `fmod(x,h) == 1 - 10 * .1` which should be almost 0. So far the stuff in your answer is not enough to explain this.

Comment: I just found a similar question asked here..http://stackoverflow.com/q/26519082/364084.

Comment: @AndyG I am still working out the result manually as per this explanation. If it works out, I will mark it as the answer

Comment: @wanderer Now that looks like an actual dupe.

Comment: @BaummitAugen yes it does. I will try to manually verify to see if it does answer the question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I tried to make it clear that the problem stemmed from `std::remainder` to compute `fmod` returning a negative value. Following the logic of the `fmod` implementation, it's no wonder that the result is basically `y`

Comment: @AndyG I still don't see how that addresses my point with the truncating assignment yielding 10.

Comment: @AndyG yes I found the explanation of std::remainder returning a -ve value along with the code for fmod implementation helpful

Comment: @wanderer The important part here is whether or not the question itself is a dupe, less whether or not the answers there are great (which they probably aren't). If we need more/better answers, I think we should use bounties / upvotes on the original.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Oh I totally agree. I didn't try to justify the behavior as correct. By the documentation of `fmod`, this behavior is a bug in my opinion. It looks like the cause of that is both by using `std::remainder` and by perhaps incompletely handling a negative result.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer and it is in my opinion a better answer than ones on http://stackoverflow.com/q/26519082/364084. It points out that the documentation of fmod() does not agree with its internal implementation due to its use of std::remainder(not mentioned in documentationn) and if we did infact tried to do what the description of fmod() said, we would have gotten 0(the expected result).  And since fmod is using std::remainder internally and expecting the behaviour of remainder() to known to the implementers of fmod(), this case could have been handled in a better manner.

Comment: As this seems to be the still current behaviour of clang and gcc, we can conclude that `fmod` is basically useless if the second parameter almost evenly divides the first, right? So you can never use it to determine this fact basically. At least for values in this range discussed here.