# Difference in Java, if any, between the % operator and the IEEEremainder() method?

Tags: java, math

In Java, is there any functional or performance difference between using the % operator to get the remainder of an integer division x / y, and the Math.IEEEremainder( x, y ) method?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971645/is-math-ieeeremainderx-y-equivalent-to-xy

Comment: Check out the [relevant JLS section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) where it is defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apart from the type difference already pointed out by John B, there's a significant difference in semantics, too.  `Math.IEEEremainder(x, y)` returns `x - n * y` where `n` is the *closest* integer to `x / y` (taking the even integer in the case of a tie), while `x % y` returns `x - n * y` where `n` is the integer part of `x / y` (i.e., `n` is the result of rounding the true value of `x / y` towards zero, instead of towards nearest).

To illustrate the difference:  `Math.IEEEremainder(9.0, 5.0)` would be `-1.0`, since the closest integer to `9.0 / 5.0` is `2`, and `9.0 - 2 * 5.0` is `-1.0`.  But `9.0 % 5.0` would be `4.0`, since the integer part of `9.0 / 5.0` is `1` and `9.0 - 1 * 5.0` is `4.0`.

Here's the [official documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#IEEEremainder%28double,%20double%29) for `Math.IEEEremainder`.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.IEEEremainder` accepts and returns `doubles` and should therefore be used when you want a `double` result. If you want the modulus, use `%` as it gives an `int` and would be more efficient than `double` arithmetic.

Comment: The result of % between two floating-point values cannot possibly be an `int`, as [NaN is one of the possible results](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3).