# c# method Math.IEEERemainder(x,y) equivalent in matlab?

Tags: c#, matlab

Is there exist a method in matlab equivalent to c# method `Math.IEEERemainder`.

Details about this method can be found here: [Is Math.IEEERemainder(x,y) equivalent to x%y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971645/is-math-ieeeremainderx-y-equivalent-to-xy)

According to IEEERemainder specifications:

```
3/2 should be -1
```

However Matlab method `mod(3,2)` returns 1 and `rem(3,2)` also returns 1.

Comment: have you seen [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) and [`rem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rem.html) in MATLAB? Also worth reading [Division and Modulus for Computer Scientists](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/151917/divmodnote.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct mathematical function would be `x-y*round(x/y)`. The only difference between this expression and `Math.IEEERemainder` is when the value of `x/y` is exactly halfway between two integers. In that case, `round(x/y)` rounds away from zero, while the rounding function in `Math.IEEERemainder` rounds to the even integer.

A function could look like this:

```
function out=IEEERemainder(x,y)
x-y.*round(x./y)
end
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite the same as `Math.IEEERemainder` in C#

Comment: You're right. I misread the rem(x,y) help. I think my edit is correct.

Comment: it work as it should. However, I wonder if there is built in matlab method.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a built in function with the same behavior. Any reason you can define the function in your code?