# C# equivalent of IEEE 754 remainder()?

Tags: c#, .net, c99, ieee-754, modulus

In C#, is there an exact equivalent of C99 / IEEE 754's [`remainder()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remainder.3.html) function?

The [C# language specification says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691374.aspx) that `operator %(double x, double y)` is "analogous to that used for integer operands, but differs from the IEEE 754 definition (in which `n` is the integer closest to `x / y`)".

For an example of the difference, this C# program outputs two 1's:

```c#
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(5.0 % 2.0);
        Console.WriteLine(3.0 % 2.0);
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/GBITYq

whereas the analogous C program outputs 1 and -1:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%f\n", remainder(5.0, 2.0));
    printf("%f\n", remainder(3.0, 2.0));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

http://ideone.com/HpuIVr

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ieeeremainder(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You are probably looking for the Math.IEEERemainder() method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971645/is-math-ieeeremainderx-y-equivalent-to-xy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method implements the IEEE 754 remainder algorithm:

[Math.IEEERemainder(double, double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ieeeremainder(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Math.IEEERemainder(5.0, 2.0));
        Console.WriteLine(Math.IEEERemainder(3.0, 2.0));
    }
}

// Output: 1, -1
```

http://ideone.com/b2Lvfx