# What's the point of Raku's 'mod' operator?

Tags: raku, integer-division, modulo, rakudo

I previously **incorrectly** thought that the [`%` operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_%) returned the *remainder* and the [`mod` operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_mod) returned the *modulus* (the remainder and modulus are the same when the operands are both positive or both negative but differ when one operand is positive and the other is negative.  Compare Raket's [remainder](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=mod#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._remainder%29%29) and [modulo](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=mod#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._modulo%29%29) functions).

However, that's not correct at all – both `%` and `mod` return the modulus; neither return the remainder.  In fact, it looks like `mod` will always return exactly the same value as `%` would have, if called with the same arguments.  As far as I can tell, the only difference is that `%` can be called with non-integer arguments, whereas `mod` throws an exception if called with anything other than `Int:D` or `int`.

So, what's the point of `mod`?  Is there some performance gain from using it (maybe by saving the optimizer some specialization work?) or is there some other difference I'm missing?

Comment: Any info to be gleaned from [speculifcations](https://design.raku.org)?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen not particularly.  S03 describes both [`%`](https://design.raku.org/S03.html#line_826) and [`mod`](https://design.raku.org/S03.html#line_855) but doesn't provide any details about why `mod` is useful.  Worth checking, though!

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** My takeaway from a quick skim of sources is that `%` is (supposed to be) the *rational* or generic modulus op, whereas `mod` is a dedicated *integer* modulus op. For some inputs they yield the same result.

The rest of this answer just references the sources I looked at.

## Doc

[`mod`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/mod):

> **Integer** modulo operator. Returns the remainder of an integer modulo operation.

[`%`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/$PERCENT_SIGN):

> Modulo operator. **Coerces to `Numeric` first**.
>
> Generally the following identity holds:
>
> ```
> my ($x, $y) = 1,2;
> $x % $y == $x - floor($x / $y) * $y
> ```

## roast

[Search of roast for `modulus`](https://github.com/Raku/roast/search?q=modulus) lists just `S03-operators/arith.t`. Leads to:

- [`infix:<%>` should return Rat when it can](https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/3409).
- ["TimToady thinks `modmap` (or whatever we decide to call it) would be a useful addition to the language"](https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/3128). (Off topic but interesting.)

## S03

> `infix:<%>`, modulo
>
> **coerces** ... then calculates the **remainder ... defined as**:
>
> `$x % $y == $x - floor($x / $y) * $y`
>
> **If both operands are of *integer or rational* type, the operator returns the corresponding `Rat` value** (except when the result does not fit into a `Rat`, as detailed in S02).
>
> `infix:<mod>`, **integer** modulo
>
> Dispatches to the `infix:<mod>` multi most appropriate to the operand types, returning a value of the same type. **Not coercive**, so fails on differing types.
>
> This **should preserve the identity**:
>
> `$x mod $y == $x - ($x div $y) * $y`

## IRC

[Search of #perl6 for `mod integer`](https://irclogs.raku.org/search.html?query=mod++integer&type=words&all-words=True&nicks=&channel=perl6&message-type=&from-yyyymmdd=2005-02-26&to-yyyymmdd=2020-04-14).

## Rakudo source code

- [`infix:<%>`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core.c/Numeric.pm6#L235-L249)
- [`infix:<mod>`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/dd2b274fd59f18584171451457b15a699f7bc76e/src/core.c/Real.pm6#L160-L161)

Comment: "If both operands are of integer or rational type, the operator returns the corresponding Rat value" Hmmm, this is *not* how `%` currently behaves – it currently returns an `Int` (/ `int`) when called with two `Int`s (/ two `int`s).  So the only difference left from S03 is that `%` tries to coerce and handles non-`Int`s whereas `mod` throws an error.  And I don't see when that behavior would be useful (unless it's for the perf reasons I speculated about in the Q).

Comment: "not how `%` currently behaves ... only difference left from S03 is that `%` tries to coerce and handles non-`Int`s." Afawct, there's just those 2 differences, right? So my guess is it's half done and @Larry would want it completed. "I don't see when that behavior would be useful". I don't, but one can safely presume that @Larry (which refers to the entire PL design team) didn't specify/speculate a difference without very good reason, given that that was their standard for all things. Sometimes stuff didn't get finished because it was controversial, sometimes lack of tuits. I'll research that.

Answer (score 2):

The 'bible' of [IEEE P754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) says this...

*Floating point remainder. This is not like a normal modulo operation, it can be negative for two positive numbers. It returns the exact value of x–(round(x/y)·y).*

Comment: I'm confused: my StackOverflow inbox claims I got an answer starting with `afaict the general idea is that mod is for exact things (Int, Rat) whereas % is for inexact things`, and links to this answer.  But the full text of this answer is currently "012345678901234567890123456789 > 30 chars\n\n per [P754][1]\n\n [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158120/math-ieeeremainder-returns-negative-results-why".  And this answer shows that it's never been edited. ???

Comment: sorry @codesections ... i was in dive/edit mode