# C# compiler number literals

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Does anyone know the full list of C# compiler number literal modifiers?

By default declaring '0' makes it an Int32 and '0.0' makes it a 'Double'. I can use the literal modifier 'f' at the end to ensure something is treated as a 'Single' instead. For example like this...

```
var x = 0;    // x is Int32
var y = 0f;   // y is Single
```

What are the other modifiers I can use? Is there one for forcing to Double, Decimal, UInt32? I tried googling for this but could not find anything. Maybe my terminology is wrong and so that explains why I am coming up blank. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
var y = 0f; // y is single
var z = 0d; // z is double
var r = 0m; // r is decimal
var i = 0U; // i is unsigned int
var j = 0L; // j is long (note capital L for clarity)
var k = 0UL; // k is unsigned long (note capital L for clarity)
```

From the [C# specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127776/where-can-you-find-the-c-language-specifications) 2.4.4.2 Integer literals and 2.4.4.3 Real literals. Take note that L and UL are preferred as opposed to their lowercase variants for clarity as recommended by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: While l is certainly valid for longs, I'd recommend using L instead - it's just as valid, and doesn't look like a "1"

Comment: @Jon Skeet: bad habit of a C programmer, added your advice.

Comment: Why is `0U` uppercase? I can't see any ambiguity with `0u`.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to have to remember them, then the compiler also accepts a cast for the same purpose (you can check the IL that the effect is the same - i.e. the compiler, not the runtime, does the cast). To borrow the earlier example:

```
    var y = (float)0; // y is single
    var z = (double)0; // z is double
    var r = (decimal)0; // r is decimal
    var i = (uint)0; // i is unsigned int
    var j = (long)0; // j is long
    var k = (ulong)0; // k is unsigned long
```

And for the record, I agree that "var" is a bad choice here; I'll happily use var for a SortedDictionary<SomeLongType, SomeOtherLongType>, but for "int" it is just lazy...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: +1 good advice using the cast, but sometimes you need to use the suffix (say, bad example, 3.14159m). I personally use the cast when I'm looking to be explicit.

Comment: The compiler treat the following identically; do you have an example where it makes a difference?
        var x = 3.14159m;
        var y = (decimal)3.14159;

Comment: @Marc Gravell: hmm, not that I can think of, just the hunch of a C/C++ programmer. I guess I don't take the same things for granted! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: To answer the question in the comment, (decimal)1.000000000000001 evaluates to 1 whereas 1.000000000000001m evaluates to 1.000000000000001. In the former case, the computer parses the literal as a double and then casts it to a decimal.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to start by [looking at the C# language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx). Most of the types are listed in there, and have a suffix:

- L = long
- F = float
- U = uint
- ulong's are a [little different](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4(VS.71).aspx)
- m = decimal (money)
- D = double

Of course, if you stop using *var* then you get around the whole problem, and your code becomes more readable (ok, thats subjective, but for something like this, it's more readable by other people:

```
var x = 0; //whats x?
float x = 0; //oh, it's a float
byte x = 0; // or not!
```

Comment: @Nic Wise: +1 stop using var ;D Although it does simplify showing which suffix goes with which type.

Comment: yeah, very good point :) I like var in general, esp in foreach statements (foreach(var a in myList)) but other than that, I'm not a huge fan.