# Limiting float to 4 decimal places

Tags: c#

This i what I am trying to achieve:

If a float has more than 4 decimal places, only keep until the first 4 dec places (do not round.)

Eg.: 111.3547698 -> 111.3547

If a float has less than 4 decimals, leave unchanged

I came across this command:

```
float example = 111.3547698;

((Math.Truncate(Example * 1000)) / 1000)
```

But I do not want to round. According to the command posted above, 111.3547698 -> 111.354

but I need it to stay: 111.3547

Comment: You need another 0.

Comment: Are you going to be doing more math with the result, or just writing it somewhere? If the latter, there are much better ways.

Comment: No, I will not be doing any more math, just want to truncate to 4 places after the decimal and show it as the result.

Comment: I tried adding another 0, but still the same answer and also it is rounding of to 3 digits.

Comment: The problem is in how you are displaying it, show that code.

Comment: hi, Scott, i did not understood, what you are asking me to show, could you please frame the question in a different way, please.

Answer (score 4):

One way to force this sort of truncating is to subtract a small amount so that Math.Round works as desired.

```
Math.Round(111.3547698 - 0.00005, 4)
```

is equivalent to

```
Math.Round(111.3547198, 4)
```

which does give you the 111.3547 that you're looking for.

The general case would be

```
Math.Round(num - 0.5/(Math.Pow(10, digits)), digits)
```

Where digits > 0

See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51951/truncate-decimal-places for a similar question/answer.

Comment: This works only for this case, but what is the value is different, this is just the example with a hard coded value, but if i want to truncate for different values, how do i do that?

Comment: added a general case to the solution above

Answer (score 0):

Your code don't even compile in last vertion of C#.

It says:

> Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float';
>   use an 'F' suffix to create a literal of this type

That mean you should read about [literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166752/c-sharp-compiler-number-literals) in C#

This peace of code that you probably copy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3814223/1849444) have literal `m` that says to compiler this number will be `decimal`. If you want to work with `float` with same peace of code and truncate 4 digits you should use `f` literal and write like this:

```
float ex = 111.3547698f;
var ex4 = (Math.Truncate(ex * 10000f)) / 10000f;
```

Comment: i tried with 10000f)) / 10000f, that is rounding off to three digits and giving the output as 111.355

Comment: = ((Math.Truncate(XXXXXX.VALUE * 10000f)) / 10000f)   -- 111.3547698 (Actual Value) ----- 111.355  (Return value)

Comment: XXXValue = ((Math.Truncate(xxxValueObj.VALUE * 10000f)) / 10000f). Where as i am trying to truncate the values which this XXXValue gives as output to 4 decimal places