# Minutes to hours in decimal + round in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, rounding, ceil

I'm trying to convert minutes to hours in decimal and round to the nearest fifteen minutes (rounded **up**).

Basically:

15 minutes = 0.25 hour

**25** minutes = **0.5 hour**

**30** minutes = **0.5 hour**

**50** minutes = **1 hour**

**60** minutes = **1 hour**

I haven't found anything relevant here on stackoverflow but another website tells me to:

```
var hours =  Math.Round((minutes * 100 ) / 60.0);
```

Which doesn't come near to the result.

I know I can't use `Math.Round()` (because it casts it to an int?). Same for `TimeSpan` (because it gives `.TotalHours` in a `double`).

What can a good approach be starting with dividing it by 60?

Comment: Actually 50 minutes would be 0.75 hour because it is closer to 45 than  to 60.

Comment: Have you tried to take Math.Ceiling(minutes/15)/4 ?

Comment: @stybl , but I'm rounding UP with 15 in my case.

Comment: @MarkBenovsky comment seems to cover all your examples

Comment: Math.Floor and Math.Ceiling will return ints. Since you want a double, I think your best bet is divide by 60.0 then use some if statements

Comment: [Thats not true](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx) @MattL.

Comment: You might need to modify it slightly to `Math.Ceiling(minutes/15D)/4`

Comment: You could start by (Minutes*100/60) and then divide the result with 0.25 If the result is a total number you are done, else round up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets think that you have minutes and want to convert them to hours (0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)

First we get what quarter it is: `Math.Ceiling(minutes / 15.0)`

`Math.Ceiling` returns you 4 if you have 3.01

And then just divide it by 4 to have quarters

```
var hours = Math.Ceiling(minutes / 15.0)/4.0;
```

Comment: @KahnKah can't you just cast the value to a `(double)`

Comment: @KahnKah edit it like this `var hours = Math.Ceiling(minutes / 15.0)/4.0;`
Or cast values to double

Comment: I can't parse it to a double @DarthJam

Comment: Thank you very much Mark

Comment: you can also use `15d` for `double` or `15m` for `decimal` https://stackoverflow.com/a/166762/89586

Answer (score 3):

Use one of

- `Math.Round(minutes / 15) * 0.25`,
- `Math.Floor(minutes / 15) * 0.25` or
- `Math.Ceiling(minutes / 15) * 0.25`

depending on the exact rounding you want (nearest, down or up).

`minutes / 15` tells you a number of quarters, which you round, then `0.25` converts to hours.