# C# language specification (hard copy)

Tags: c#

I am trying to get hold of a hard copy of the C# language spec and heard you can get in touch with Microsoft to do this. I have contacted them by phone and they barely knew what C# was let alone where to get a copy of the spec!

Can anyone shed a bit of light on this please??

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx ...does this help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can you find the C# Language Specifications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127776/where-can-you-find-the-c-sharp-language-specifications)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get a copy of the ECMA spec free from ECMA (in hard copy) - or at least you used to be able to.

For the Microsoft spec, you can buy the [annotated copy from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321741765), or of course your other favourite book supplier. I can thoroughly recommend this version - the annotations are really interesting. (Well, mine aren't all that hot, but the *other* annotators are really smart :)

There are soft copies for free, of course - I maintain a [page with links to the the various versions](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Specifications.aspx).

Comment: I saw the one you got in this video.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGbQiguuUGc 

But does the free hard copy sent from ECMA will be updated to latest c# version?

Comment: @SenJacob: I don't know of any plans for ECMA to go up-to-date. I suggest you get the hard copy of the Microsoft C# 5 spec.

Comment: Thank you. I already have your C# in depth 2nd edition and I love it. Could you recommend the best book to learn c# design patterns, please?

Comment: Hmm, let me search one for myself then.. Why don't you write one? Please think about it.

Comment: @SenJacob: I only have so much time... I do have a screencast about C# design patterns on Pluralsight though.

Comment: Wow, thank you. For later reference, the link is: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/csharp-design-strategies