# Performant, idiomatic way to concatenate two chars that are not in a list into a string

Tags: f#

I've done most of my development in C# and am just learning F#. Here's what I want to do in C#:

```
string AddChars(char char1, char char2) => char1.ToString() + char2.ToString();
```

EDIT: added `ToString()` method to the C# example.

I want to write the same method in F# and I don't know how to do it other than this:

```
let addChars char1 char2 = Char.ToString(char1) + Char.ToString(char2)
```

Is there a way to add concatenate these `char`s into a `string` without converting both into `string`s first?

---

Sidenote:

I also have considered making a `char` array and converting that into a `string`, but that seems similarly wasteful.

```
let addChars (char1:char) (char2: char) = string([|char1; char2|])
```

Comment: The C# version of your code is not going to do what you think it will do - it won't concatenate the characters into a string. It will treat the `char`s as `int`s, and adding them together will result in an `int` as well. In fact, to do what you want would require doing something similar to what you are already doing in the F# version.

Comment: The most idiomatic way would be `sprintf "%c%c" c1 c2`, I think. It's almost certainly slower than the `String [| c1; c2 |]` approach that Abion47 recommends, but I find `sprintf` to be more F#-idiomatic than the .Net `String` constructor. So unless this is in a tight inner loop where performance *really matters* (don't optimize prematurely!), I'd recommend `sprintf "%c%c" c1 c2`.

Comment: @Abion47 I hate when I goof in questions like this! Thanks for the correction and for the thorough answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment, your C# code is not going to do what you want ( i.e. concatenate the characters into a string). In C#, adding a `char` and a `char` will result in an `int`. The reason for this is because the `char` type doesn't define a `+` operator, so C# reverts to the nearest compatable type that does, which just happens to be `int`. ([Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851809/char-char-int-why))

So to accomplish this behavior, you will need to do something similar to what you are already trying to do in F#:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';

// This is the wrong way to concatenate chars, because the
// chars will be treated as ints and the result will be 195.
Console.WriteLine(a + b);                              

// These are the correct ways to concatenate characters into
// a single string. The result of all of these will be "ab".
// The third way is the recommended way as it is concise and 
// involves creating the fewest temporary objects.
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString() + b.ToString());        
Console.WriteLine(Char.ToString(a) + Char.ToString(b));
Console.WriteLine(new String(new[] { a, b }));
```

*(See [https://dotnetfiddle.net/aEh1FI)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aEh1FI)_)*

F# is the same way in that concatenating two or more `char`s doesn't result in a `String`. Unlike C#, it results instead in another `char`, but the process is the same - the `char` values are treated like `int` and added together, and the result is the `char` representation of the sum.

So really, the way to concatenate `char`s into a `String` in F# is what you already have, and is the direct translation of the C# equivalent:

```
let a = 'a'
let b = 'b'

// This is still the wrong way (prints 'Ã')
printfn "%O" (a + b)

// These are still the right ways (prints "ab")
printfn "%O" (a.ToString() + b.ToString())
printfn "%O" (Char.ToString(a) + Char.ToString(b))
printfn "%O" (String [| a;b |]) // This is still the best way
```

*(See [https://dotnetfiddle.net/ALwI3V)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ALwI3V)_)*

The reason the "String from char array" approach is the best way is two-fold. First, it is the most concise, since you can see that that approach offers the shortest line of code in both languages (and the difference only increases as you add more and more `char`s together). And second, only one temporary object is created (the array) before the final `String`, whereas the other two methods involve making two separate temporary `String` objects to feed into the final result.

<s>(Also, I'm not sure if it works this way as the `String` constructors are hidden in external sources, but I imagine that the array passed into the constructor would be used as the `String`'s backing data, so it wouldn't end up getting wasted at all.)</s> `String`s are immutable, but using the passed array directly as the created `String`'s backing data could result in a situation where a reference to the array could be held elsewhere in the program and jeopardize the `String`'s immutability, so this speculation wouldn't fly in practice. (Credit: @CaringDev)

---

Another option you could do in F# that could be more idiomatic is to use the `sprintf` function to combine the two characters (Credit: @rmunn):

```
let a = 'a'
let b = 'b'
let s = sprintf "%c%c" a b

printfn "%O" s 

// Prints "ab"
```

*(See [https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pp9Tee)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pp9Tee)_)*

A note of warning about this method, however, is that it is almost certainly going to be much slower than any of the other three methods listed above. That's because instead of processing array or `String` data directly, `sprintf` is going to be performing more advanced formatting logic on the output. (I'm not in a position where I could benchmark this myself at the moment, but plugged into @TomasPetricek's benckmarking code below, I wouldn't be surprised if you got performance hits of 10x or more.)

This might not be a big deal as for a single conversion it will still be far faster than any end-user could possibly notice, but be careful if this is going to be used in any performance-critical code.

Comment: As strings are immutable, I guess the array needs to be copied, otherwise holding a reference to it would be unsafe.

Comment: @CaringDev That is true. I'd still see the third alternative as being far more performant than the other two since the straight copy of array memory would be much more efficient than the processing of two other String objects. (Tomas Petricek's answer confirms this.)

Comment: Sure, performance wise this is best. The comment is targeted at the last parenthesized paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @Abion47 already lists all the possible sensible methods I can think of. If you are interested in performance, then you can run a quick experiment using the F# Interactive `#time` feature:

```
#time 
open System
open System.Text

let a = 'a'
let b = 'b'
```

Comparing the three methods, the one with `String [| a; b |]` turns out to be about twice as fast as the methods involving `ToString`. In practice, that's probably not a big deal unless you are doing millions of such operations (as my experiment does), but it's an interesting fact to know:

```
// 432ms, 468ms, 472ms
for i in 0 .. 10000000 do
  let s = a.ToString() + b.ToString()
  ignore s

// 396ms 440ms, 458ms
for i in 0 .. 10000000 do
  let s = Char.ToString(a) + Char.ToString(b)
  ignore s

// 201ms, 171ms, 170ms
for i in 0 .. 10000000 do
  let s = String [| a;b |]
  ignore s
```

Comment: Upvoting for the #time suggestion; I didn't know that existed.