# Why does string addition result is so weird?

Tags: c#, string

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int num = 1;
     string number = num.ToString();
     Console.WriteLine(number[0]);
     Console.WriteLine(number[0] + number[0]);
}
```

I expect the output of `1` and `11` but I'm getting `1` and `98`. What am I missing?

Comment: That isn't string addition it is char addition.  Using indexing returns a char not a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of `number[0]` is `char`, not `string` - you're not performing any string concatenation. Instead, you've got a `char` with value 49 (the UTF-16 value for '1'). There's no `+(char, char)` operator, so both operands are being promoted to `int` and you're performing integer addition.

So this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(number[0] + number[0]);
```

is effectively this:

```
char op1 = number[0];
int promoted1 = op1;

char op2 = number[0];
int promoted2 = op2;

int sum = promoted1 + promoted2;
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

(It's possible that logically the promotion happens after both operands have been evaluated - I haven't checked the spec, and as it won't fail, it doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 7):

Because of [], this give the first char of the string.

`number[0] + number[0]` is doing 49 + 49 (the ascii code of char 1);

I think you want to do this :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = 1;
    string number = num.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(number);
    Console.WriteLine(number + number);
}
```

Comment: See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851809/char-char-int-why

Comment: Thank you Dan for explanation and thanks to you Alexander for additional content on the topic.