# Why (char) + (char) = (int) in C?

Tags: c

Is it for the same reason as [char + char = int? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851809/char-char-int-why) ?

I got different results on this source code by different compilers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char a = 100, b = 100;
    printf("%d\n", a + b);
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d\n", a + b);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);` invokes *undefined behavior*. This will be actually dangerous because typically `char` is smaller than `int`.

Comment: Also note that whether `char` is signed is implementation-defined. What different results did you get?

Comment: @MikeCAT ok I see, then could you tell me why sizeof(a+b) is equal to 4?

Comment: Re "*why sizeof(a+b) is equal to 4?*", [Integer promotion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integer-promotions-in-c/)

Comment: Integer promotion happens when you sum 2 chars as well

Comment: @MikeCAT I put a=100 and b=100. the second a+b = 200 in VS, and 100 in Code Blocks & Dev-Cpp

Comment: [c - Implicit type promotion rules - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Comment: Use `%hhd` to read `char` via `scanf()`. `%d` is for reading `int`.

Comment: @MikeCAT, TonyTannous, ikegami Thank you! That was because of the integer promotion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different results because `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b)` is incorrect. For each `%d`, `scanf` expects the address of an `int` object, but you provided the addresses of `char` objects. This results in (dangerous) undefined behaviour.

For `char` objects, use the following:

```c
scanf("%hhd%hhd", &a, &b)    // In a environment with signed chars
  -or-
scanf("%hhu%hhu", &a, &b)    // In a environment with unsigned chars
```